# Нужна помощь с форматированием BigDouble (unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код игры-кликера. По нажатию кнопки, увеличивает значение moneyAmount на moneyPerClick и выводит на экран.
Так же есть Апгрейд, при каждой покупке которого, значение upgradePrice и moneyPerClick умножается на multiplier:

```
    private BigDouble moneyAmount;
    private BigDouble multiplier = 1.15;
    private BigDouble moneyPerClick = 20;
    private BigDouble upgradePrice = 50;    
    public GameObject DisplayValue;

    //Добавление денег за клик
    public void ClickToCreate()
    {
        if (!UpgradeMenu.upgradeIsOpen)
        { 
            moneyAmount += moneyPerClick;
            DisplayValue.GetComponent<Text>().text = "$: " + FormatMoney(moneyAmount);
        }
    }

    //Покупка апгрейда
    public void FirstUpgrade()
    {
        if (moneyAmount >= upgradePrice)
        {
            moneyAmount -= upgradePrice;
            upgradePrice *= multiplier;
            moneyPerClick *= multiplier;
            DisplayValue.GetComponent<Text>().text = "$: " + FormatMoney(moneyAmount);
        }
    }
```

Ниже есть метод FormatMoney (написанный не мной), и делался он под тип данных decimal.Проблема для меня в том, что в BigDouble значения состоят из двух частей, Мантисса и Экспонента, и значения используются не больше 100(вроде). А метод FormatMoney работает с decimal и делит огромные цифры на 1000, после плюсует префикс из массива в конец числа.

Нужно, чтобы было так: если количество  нулей меньше 14-ти, то после числа добавлялись префиксы из массива, если нулей больше 14-ти то BigDouble сам приписывает экспоненту Е+15,Е+16... и т.д.

```
    static string[] names = { "", "K", "M", "B", "T", "A", "Aa", "Ab", "Ac", "Ad", "Ae", "Af", "Ag", "Ah" };
    //Форматирование значений и добавление префикса
    public static string FormatMoney(decimal value)
    {
        int n = 0;
        while (n + 1 < names.Length && value >= 1000m)
        {
            value /= 1000m;
            n++;
        }

        if (value <= 1000m)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}{1}", Math.Round(value, 0), names[n]);
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Format("{0}{1}", Math.Round(value, 2), names[n]);
        }
    }
```

И ещё хотел бы узнать как округлять значения BigDouble без префикса, потому что там выводит, пример: 1,2658560727854Е+15 и т.д. А нужно так, пример: 1,265Е+15.
Round`ом не получается, потому что у BigDouble нет такой перегрузки как в обычном Math, где вторым аргументом указывается число знаков после запятой. Прошу помощи, уже неделю ломаю голову.

Скриншоты:
Значение `1360`, а мне нужно `1.36к`:
[image]

Длина значения увеличивается от значения ***е***. Тут должно быть число `5.400М`:
[image]

Тут очень длинное значение, мне нужно его как-то сократить до двух-трёх знаков после запятой, т.е должно число должно выглядеть так: `5.400Е+15`:
[image]

Comment: Я не совсем понял, что вы хотите: чтобы не было работа с числами больше 100, чтобы экспоненты приписывались только при n>10^14, чтобы округлялось до трех знаков? Слишком много вопросов для одного поста...

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы в BigDouble значения больше тысячи имели префикс "К", после миллиона - префикс "М" и т.д. до префикса "Ah"(он 14 по счёту в массиве). А после 14-ти нулей BigDouble сам приписывает значение экспоненты в конце, так что буквы из массива больше не нужны.

Comment: А сейчас у вас это не работает?

Comment: Добавил скрины. Только описание к ним почему-то не добавилось или я не вижу просто. В общем суть: на первом скрине должно выводиться значение 1.36к, на втором- 5.400М, а на последнем должно быть значение 5.400Е+15, т.к BigDouble выше  на значения выше 14-ти нулей ставит свой префикс.

Comment: Неужели нет знатоков?

Comment: Если вы хотите функцию FormatMoney, принимающую мантиссу и экспоненту, как написали в комментарии мне, то в чем вообще проблема? Просто округляем мантиссу как надо (сколько знаков до запятой, сколько после). При изменении количества знаков до запятой увеличиваем/уменьшаем мантиссу. Выводим мантиссу, затем значение из names, с учетом, что один суффикс из Names подходит для трех "степеней" чисел (см. мой ответ). Если массива не хватает, выводим суффикс "E+n", где n - экспонента

Comment: @МаксимФисман Можете восстановить ваш ответ? Он мне был ещё нужен

Comment: Он же не отвечал на вопрос! Вы про BigDouble, ответ про decimal. Ну,\ ок, как хотите.

Comment: @МаксимФисман Я хотел посмотреть, как сделать 3 поколения суфиксов, но всё равно не смог применить её в готовой реализации. Т.к в BigDouble после того, как мантисса доходит до 9-ти, а потом становится снова 1(единица)  и увеличивает экспоненту. При моих проверках на экспонент(которые я давал в ответе), получается, например число 10к и 100к не может выводить. Выводит только одну цифру в мантиссе. Но вы всё ещё можете помочь, если есть желание.

Comment: Если не трудно, посмотрите файл https://github.com/NickFerdenes/Click/blob/main/BigDouble.cs. Там есть мой метод, называется MyFormat. Это измененный метод  FormatExponential

Comment: @МаксимФисман нужна ваша помощь

Answer (score 1):

Сразу скажу, что я не совсем понял, что вам нужно, но переделал вашу функцию вот таким образом (комментарии ниже):

```
static int Accuracy = 3; // Точность (чисел после запятой)  
    
static string FormatMoney(decimal value)
{
    int n = 0;
    while (Math.Abs(value) >= 1000) {
        value /= 1000;
    n++;
    }
        
    // Option 1:
    value = Math.Round(value, Accuracy);
        
    // Option 2:
    /*
    decimal RoundedValue = Math.Round(value, Accuracy);
    value = (RoundedValue == (int) RoundedValue ? (int) RoundedValue : RoundedValue);
    */
        
    if (n < names.Length) {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}", value, names[n]);
    }
    else {
        n *= 3;
        while (Math.Abs(value) >= 10) {
        value /= 10;
            n++;
        }
        return string.Format("{0}E+{1}", value, n);
    }
}
```

Скажу сразу, что мне кажется, вы неправильно пытаетесь расставлять суффиксы. Для вас при умножении числа на 10 автоматически берется следующий суффикс, однако каждый суффикс должен продерживаться **3** "поколения":

```
2000 -> 2K
20000 -> 20K
200000 -> 200K
---
3100000 -> 3.1M
31000000 -> 31M
310000000 -> 310M
```

Именно таким образом работает мой код.

**ВАЖНО:** в коде отмечены две опции: `Option 1` точно выполняет ваше условие, `Option 2` поможет от случаев, когда при округлении до X знаков после запятой, эти знаки - нули. Пример:

```
2000000003 -> 2.000B (при Option1)
2000000003 -> 2B (при Option2)
```

**ПРИМЕРЫ** работы этой функции `при Accuracy=3 и на Option1`

```
ВВОД:
0
1
12345
1234567890
12345.6789
10000000000000m
1000000000000000000000000000m
282572562723657m
3000000007

ВЫВОД:
0
1
12.345K
1.235B
12.346K
10T
1E+27
282.573T
3.000B
```

Если указываете огромные числа напрямую (не decimal переменными), то обязательно добавлять `m`:

```
FormatMoney(100000000000000m);
FormatMoney(2825725627236572m);
```

> P.S. Проще была бы функция `FormatMoney`, которая бы принимала ваш `BigDouble`, то есть мантиссу и экспоненту. Я делал с `decimal`, как было в вопросе.

> P.P.S. Я мог неверно понять, что вам нужно. Если это так, пишите в комментариях, я попытаюсь помочь. Если я понял все верно и вы примите ответ, то я удалю `P.P.S.`

Comment: Извиняюсь, если я не совсем правильно сформулировал изначальный вопрос. Для игры нужны значения, невероятно огромные (до Е+1000 и больше) и чтобы ими можно было оперировать(вычитать, умножать между собой). Метод FormatMoney с типом decimal не подходит под такие операции, вот я и решил использовать тип BigDouble. Получается, нужно изменить FormatMoney(decimal) под тип BigDouble.

Comment: @NickEloye Но BigDouble это ваш собственный кастомный класс? В C# Такого же нет. Тогда выкладывайте его реализацию

Comment: BigDouble взят из решения на GitHub`e. Вот оно - https://github.com/Razenpok/BreakInfinity.cs